# Flutter App fails to run on physical android device with com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

This is the output that I get from my run log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G965U in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Also, surprisingly, running the same code on an emulator doesn't have any issues at all and builds fine.

Let me know If I should share any specific files to help answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The gradle I was using was unsupported. I downgraded my gradle to 3.5.0 and it worked!!